# How do I get the last element of a list of lists?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to return the last element of a list of list, for example if the list was [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]] it would return [1,2,3]. Currently I have

```
getLast :: [[a]] -> [a]
getLast [[x]] = [x]
getLast (_:xs) = getLast xs
```

But this create type errors. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you change your second line to `getLast [x] = x` ? Also, you don't need to use the fact that the lists elements are lists themselves. You can write your function more generally as `getLast :: [a] -> a`

Comment: What should happen if an empty list is passed, so `getLast []`?

Comment: Your first pattern will only fire if the *inner* list contains *exactly* one element (so no empty list, or a list with two or more elements).

Answer (score 3):

This is just the prelude function [`last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:last)

> last :: [a] -> a
>
> Extract the last element of a list, which must be finite and non-empty.

It is defined in the Haskell source as:

```hs
-- | Extract the last element of a list, which must be finite and non-empty.
last                    :: [a] -> a
last [x]                =  x
last (_:xs)             =  last xs
last []                 =  errorEmptyList "last"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the meaning of `[[a]]` in a type signature is quite different than the meaning of `[[x]]` in a pattern.  In the type signature, the type:

```
getLast :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

says that `getLast` takes an argument that's a list of lists of elements of type `a`.  Of course, one such list is `[[1]]`, but another such list is `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`.  The single `a` in `[[a]]` doesn't restrict the number of elements -- it's a list of any number of lists of any number of `a`s, not a list of a single list of a single `a`.

Patterns are different.  When you write:

```
getLast [[x]] = ...
```

this only matches a list consisting of a *single* list that consists of a *single* value `x`.  So, it matches:

```
getLast [[1]]
```

but it doesn't match:

```
getLast [[1,2,3]]
```

In your example, `getLast [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`, grinds through the recursive pattern:

```
getLast (_:xs) = getLast xs
```

to evaluate:

```
getLast [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
= getLast [[1,2],[1,2,3]]
= getLast [[1,2,3]]
```

but this last step doesn't match any of the defined patterns.  It doesn't match:

```
getLast (_:xs) = ...
```

because the list `[[1,2,3]]` only has one element.  But, it doesn't match:

```
getLast [[x]] = ...
```

either, because the inner list `[1,2,3]` has three elements, not one like the pattern `[x]`.  It would match the pattern:

```
getLast [[x,y,z]] = ...
```

but you don't have that pattern, so you get an error with:

```
> getLast [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
*** Exception: ...: Non-exhaustive patterns in function getLast
```

To match a list consisting of a single list of *any* number of elements, you want to use the pattern:

```
getLast [lst] = ...
```

Note that you don't need to use any special syntax to indicate that `lst` is supposed to match a list type `[a]`.  GHC already knows this from the type signature.

So, you can write:

```
getLast :: [[a]] -> [a]
getLast [lst] = lst
getLast (_:xs) = getLast xs
```

and now `getLast` works fine:

```
> getLast [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
[1,2,3]
```

As was pointed out in @AdamSmith's answer, you don't actually need `getLast`, because the existing function `last` for getting the last element of a list works fine on lists of lists, too:

```
> last [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
[1,2,3]
```